# whole map turns red after adding colour aestethic ggplot + ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2

My ggmap turns all red after trying to add a `colour` aestethic to the `stat_summary_hex,` everything else works fine.

Code

```
map.querySold  <- function(return.query) {

  # Specify target destination vo = vänstra övre , hu = högra undre
  vo.lon  <- min(return.query$location.position.longitude)
  vo.lat  <- max(return.query$location.position.latitude)

  hu.lon  <- max(return.query$location.position.longitude)
  hu.lat  <- min(return.query$location.position.latitude)

  # Set map 
  map <- get_map(location=c(vo.lon, vo.lat, hu.lon, hu.lat), zoom= 11, maptype = "roadmap", color = "bw")

  # Create map
  ggmap(map) + 
    stat_summary_hex(data = return.query, aes(x = location.position.longitude, y = location.position.latitude, z = sqrmPrice, colour = sqrmRent), alpha = 0.5 , fun = mean) +
    scale_fill_gradient(name = "Average sold sqrm-price", low = 'green', high = 'red') +
    theme_hl()

}
```

Data

```
 sqrmRent sqrmPrice location.position.longitude location.position.latitude
1  (50,100]  26373.63                    17.84024                   59.37254
2  (50,100]  38321.17                    18.03322                   59.26387
3 (100,150]  78913.04                    17.98254                   59.29965
4  (50,100]  51630.43                    17.93659                   59.34115
5  (50,100]  51000.00                    18.01421                   59.30183
6  (50,100]  76161.62                    18.00596                   59.33852
```

With colour aestethic on
[image]

Without colour aestethic on

[image]

table(return.query$sqrmRent) as requested

```
> table(return.query$sqrmRent)

       [0,50]  (50,100] (100,150] (150,200] (200,250] 
        13939     23898        51         1         0
```

Link to whole return.query data

http://www.filedropper.com/stackoverflow_1

Comment: Can you post the code for the second plot?

Comment: It is the same code, but with the colour aestethic deleted

Comment: I can reproduce the issue...

Fact: There are only 2 distinct values within sqrmRent, whereas in the other columns, all values are different. I've never used `stat_summary_hex` before, but is that maybe how the function reacts to this kind of data? Also, `color` is not one of the parameters that is listed to be understood by `stat_summary_hex` in the help section.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the output from `ggplot_build`, it looks like the data is first sorted by the `y` value, in this case `location.position.latitude`.  So, you can sort the `sqrmRent` in the same fashion, and color the hexes by that variable outside of the `aes` call.  Note that the sorting seems to be by y then by x, so if there are data points that share a y-value, they would need to be secondarily sorted by x-value.  This is more of a hack than a proper solution, but to add the labels, you can add a dummy geom (here `geom_line`) colored by the `sqrmRent`.

```
  ggmap(map) +
    stat_summary_hex(data = return.query, aes(x = location.position.longitude,
                         y = location.position.latitude, z = sqrmPrice),
                     color=return.query$sqrmRent[order(return.query$location.position.latitude)],
                     alpha=0.5, fun = mean) +
    scale_fill_gradient(name = "Average sold sqrm-price", low = 'green', high = 'red') +
    geom_line(data=return.query, aes(x=1, y=1, color=sqrmRent)) +
    scale_color_manual(values=1:2, labels=levels(return.query$sqrmRent))
```

[image]

Comment: Thing is the dataset shown above is only a subset of the whole data. When I try to use your code i get the error message:  Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 4 needed but only 2 provided.

Comment: @uncool try changing the `1:2` to `seq_along(levels(return.query$sqrmRent))`.  Double check that the proper hexes get colored correctly, I can't guarantee this works all the time.

Comment: Then I get another error message: Error: Incompatible lengths for set aesthetics: colour, alpha

Comment: @uncool is `seq_along(levels(return.query$sqrmRent))` not giving 4 values?  I can't try guess at your errors without data.

Comment: Ahh. I'm using return.query$sqrmRent  <- cut(x.sold$sqrmRent, breaks = seq(0, max(x.sold$sqrmRent, na.rm = TRUE), 500), include.lowest = TRUE) to generate the factor levels. For my full dataset it gives 5 levels

Comment: I've added a link to a csv file containing the table(result.query$sqrmRent) data in the OP.

Comment: @uncool that should be 5 values right?  `sqrmRent` is supposed to be your factor resulting from the `cut`.

Comment: Yes. Running the whole dataset generated 5 factor levels (values).

Comment: then why is the table a huge list of floats?  it should be 5 integers

Comment: Ohh sorry! I thought you wanted to have the original data. Just a sec.

Comment: @uncool ok, you see there is a factor level with 0 data points, try adding the line `return.query <- droplevels(return.query)` to the beginning of your function.

Comment: Tried it. Now I get the error message: Error: Incompatible lengths for set aesthetics: colour, alpha. This also happens when I tried to cut the factor levels to just two levels as in the original OP example (no 0 value factor levels then).

Comment: Well. Putting everyting inside the aes() made it somewhat work. But now everything is shown but the graph is still covered in a single colour as my original problem...

Comment: @uncool no, that makes no sense to me, but if it's working great ;)

Comment: It works, but only if you only have 2 factor levels(!). As soon as you go above that it appears to create a HUGE hexagon on the map, which is causing all the red colour in the OP graph.

Comment: @uncool ok, I guess just post a link to the whole `result.query`

Comment: I have updated the OP with the data in it's raw format.

Comment: @uncool so there are multiple points inside the bins, but how do you determine what color the bin should be since the points can have different levels of the `sqrmRent` factor

Comment: Sorry for such a late reply. Well the colour of the bin should correspond to the average value of the sqrmRent observations for that hexagon area. Thus there should not be multiple points inside the bins.

Comment: I believe the colour aestethic is not being calculated as the average of all values for that certain area (as it is for the sqrmPrice), thus we see this strange behaviour?